# Как зайти на сайт, если его dns отключен?

Tags: веб-программирование, сервер, dns, backend

Есть сайт, зайти на него не получается. Есть ip сервера 185.143.56.255  где лежит этот сайт. Нужно как-то зайти на него, я чайник, возможно нужно как-то включить dns, или возможно к сайту можно обратиться через ip, а не через домен, как-то так: edu.185.143.56.255.com(не работает)?

Comment: ip адрес уже сопоставлен с его именем (чем и занимается dns-сервер). Так что заходите по ip

Comment: @Justicet, доменное имя передаётся http серверу. и таким образом он может по ip может отдавать совсем не то, что он отдаёт при обращении по имени.

Comment: @Fat-Zer Ваше уточнение имеет смысл при наличии нескольких ресурсов, различающихся именами, на одном ip. Я же указал в стандартном варианте: один ip - одно имя.

Comment: @Justicet, даже при одном ресурсе всё зависит от настроек сервера — он может просто ничего не отдавать по ip...  а с доменом третьего уровня, как у OP'а, на этом ip практически наверняка будет что-то ещё крутиться...

Comment: @Fat-Zer по большому счёту, инициатор не осветил никаких подробностей. Я в своих постах предполагаю, что необходимо попасть на сервер для выполнения настроек данного сайта. Поэтому, что нам будет отдавать http-сервер абсолютно все равно, т.к не предполагается его использовать. Вот самый главный вопрос для ТС: что значит "попасть на сайт"? Что мы хотим сделать-то?

Answer (score 2):

1. Ищите в своей системе файл `hosts`. Во всяких линуксах это как правило `/etc/hosts`, в виндовсах это - `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
2. Добавляете в этот файл строку (и сохраняете файл):

   185.156.41.232       edu.quarnuts.com
3. Открываете браузер, и набираете в нем http://edu.quarnuts.com/