# Как использовать DNS через роутер?

Tags: wifi, dns, router, lan, ethernet

Имеется локальная компьютерная сеть, в которую включен компьютер с web-клиентом, и WiFi-роутер через WAN порт. Имеется также устройство с web-сервером и DNS-сервером, оно подключено к роутеру через WiFi.

Нужно: web-клиенту (браузеру) на компьютере подключиться к web-серверу на WiFi устройстве по доменному имени.

Что сделано: в настройках роутера проброшен порт 80 с WiFi-устройства на порт 8080 во внешнюю сеть.

Что происходит: браузер компьютера может соединяться с web-сервером и работать с ним, но только по IP-адресу роутера. Через браузер мобильного телефона, подключенного к той же WiFi сети, могу зайти на web-сервер и по адресу, и по доменному имени.

Проблема: не знаю, что настроить, чтобы использовать DNS-сервер Wi-Fi устройства.

На всякий случай приложу рисунок системы.
[image: Схема сети]

Upd. Привожу настройки пересылки, сделанные мной в роутере.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Роутер TL-WR842ND.

Comment: 1. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts 2. [один из дубликатов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/870473/178576)

Comment: Ваш комментарий никак не связан с моим вопросом. Необходимо использовать существующий DNS, а не править hosts вручную.

Comment: хорошо. и что именно мешает вам воспользоваться «существующим dns-сервером»?

Comment: То, что я не могу его "пробросить" через роутер. В этом, собственно, и заключается вопрос. Web-сервер смог, а DNS-сервер не знаю как.

Comment: так прочитайте инструкцию к вашему роутеру. ключевые слова для поиска: forwarding udp 53

Comment: Я пытался сделать проброс 53 порта WiFi устройства на 53 порт роутера. В настройках компьютера добавил в качестве DNS-сервера IP-адрес роутера. Но браузер на компьютере все равно не распознает доменное имя. Есть подозрение, что я что-то не сделал или сделал не так.